# GPS distance calculations are wrong

Tags: gps, gsm

I am working with an l80 GPS module, calculating distance using GPS coordinates. When I check total distance in my office, sometimes it will correctly display "0" but sometimes it shows "9223372036854775808.775808" and sometimes it shows "2.18654".

This is the code I'm using:

```
double distance(double lat1, double lon1, double lat2, double lon2, char unit) {
  //double theta, dist;
  theta = lon1 - lon2;
  dist = sin(deg2rad(lat1)) * sin(deg2rad(lat2)) + cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * cos(deg2rad(theta));
  dist = acos(dist);
  dist = rad2deg(dist);
  //dist = dist * 60 * 1.1515;
  dist = dist * 60 * 1.609344;
  dist+=dist;
  return (dist);
}

double deg2rad(double deg) {
  return (deg * pi / 180);
}

double rad2deg(double rad) {
  return (rad * 180 / pi);
}
```

Here is a sample of my output:

```
old_lat:13.006952    old_lon:80.257065   new_lat:13.006952    new_lon:80.257065 Total distance: 0.000000

old_lat:13.006949    old_lon:80.257065   new_lat:13.006948   new_lon:80.257065Total distance: 9223372036854775808.775808
```

Comment: Possibly a divide by zero error...well as close to zero as you can get with double floats..?

Comment: There are a few problems with this question. I have no idea how your code works - it obviously doesn't create the output you've provided, since there are no print statements in your program. I also don't see any effort on your part: you haven't told us what you've tried (if anything). You need to do some debugging on your own, first.

Comment: Your acos function is being fed an out-of-bounds value. More than likely there is a floating point representation or rounding issue which is causing the input to go slightly over 1. A limit test before the acos will fix this, but you should really analyse the code for other floating point corner cases.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it should probabyl be on stack overflow, which is for purely programming issues.

Comment: Is this bug reproducable: Does it always happen with the values: ld_lat:13.006949    old_lon:80.257065   new_lat:13.006948   new_lon:80.257065Total distance: 9223372036854775808.775808 ? Write a test program, that calls your distance() function with that values.